# C# Xamarin Select multiple values of same type from List

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, charts, xamarin.android

I was wondering how to select multiple values of same type from a list...

To be more specific:

```
public class price
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRICE { get; set; }
    public string TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
}
```

This is my List called price. Now I want for example, if this is my json output to send to list:

```
{
"Products": [[{
            "NAME": "Shirt",
            "PRICE": "25.0",
            "TIMESTAMP": "2018-03-19 06:58:24"
        }
    ], [{
            "NAME": "Pants",
            "PRICE": "30.0",
            "TIMESTAMP": "2018-03-19 06:58:16"
        }
    ], [{
            "NAME": "Shirt",
            "PRICE": "20.0",
            "TIMESTAMP": "2018-03-19 06:58:17"
        }
    ]]
}
```

So I want to return the values from a specific Name, like Shirt. When I choose Shirt, I want the values: 25.0 - 20.0. Then I want to create a graph with all the values from NAME=Shirt orderby oldest first (Like a chart).
 I receive a json from a link, parse it and put it in a List like this:

```
string link = @"http://*****/getprices.php";
string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(link);
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var pricePropery = jObject["Prices"] as JArray;
List<price> PriceList = new List<price>();
foreach (var property in pricePropery) 
{
    var propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<price>>(property.ToString());

    PriceList.AddRange(propertyList);
}
```

The thing is that the json has a couple times the same NAME with only a different PRICE and TIMESTAMP, so I want to select all the Prices of the value "NAME" and sort it by the oldest Price by using the TIMESTAMP above.

Now I want to make a chart by using microcharts. To create a chart, you have to do something like this:

```
PriceChart.Chart = new PointChart { Entries = Source };
```

So I replaced "Source" by PriceList, but thats not going to work.

So how am I supposed to do this...

EDIT: When I use this code:

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice = 
    from p in pricePropery
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP ).First();
```

How am I supposed to use it as source of the chart, because this is not going to work:

```
PriceChart.Chart = new PointChart { Entries = singleNameWithOldestPrice };
```

I cannot convert a List to a source of a PointChart.

Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you want is

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice = 
    from p in pricePropery
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP ).First()
```

Comment: And do I get all the prices from a name sort by oldest first, or just 1 price (oldest)?

Comment: I've add another part to my question!

Comment: have you tried it? it will give you an enumerable of all items, if there are multiple items in the origin, it will only return the first one based on your sorting logic

Comment: That's not really what I want, I want from a specific name, all the prices that are stored in the List. So there are multiple Shirts in the List with all different prices. Like my example, I want from Shirt: 25.0 - 20.0 .... With all those values I can create a graph.

Comment: then just do groupby, and then orderby, you don't need `First`, so you will get a list of Group, key is the Name, value is a list of all items. Any answer is meant to be a hint, dump that code to LinqPad and try it, adjust to meet what you really need

Comment: And how can I use that variable as Entry for a chart, because it says that it can't convert a List to an Entery for a chart?

Comment: I don't know how Xamarin point chart works, but you probably want to use a Line Chart or similar. Here is some discussion might give you another hint https://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamic-data-binding-of-a-chart The idea will be similar, because you are basically feeding a list or a dictionary to a UI control